# Cannot read property getSourceFile of null angular 2

Tags: angular, components

I started learning angular2 . I have created starting application and deleted some component manually then it started giving this error how I can solve this error
I am not confirmed that either this error caused due to deleting component or due to other reason.

[image]

My package.json file is all packeges included

```
{
"name": "my-app",
"version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.3",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.4.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
}
```

Comment: You'll have to also change the app.module.ts file as it won't be able to find the component that you just deleted.

Comment: I have deleted from app.module.ts too @SiddharthAjmera

Comment: Tried breaking and running the app again?

Comment: oh it works thank you man @SiddharthAjmera

Comment: Sometimes, at least on Windows systems [sad face], one will get this problem associated with locked resources (files) that should be released in order for a `ng build --watch` to work. Here we're using Unlocker tool to release locked files. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting my ng server solved my problem